# List directories by date and it drops a single item from array... am I missing something?

Tags: php, file, date, directory, ksort

Code:

```
    $files = array();
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
       $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }

    //krsort will sort in reverse order
    krsort($files);

    foreach($files as $file){
        if ($file == "." or $file == ".." or $file == "thumbs" or $file == "Thumbs.db" or strpos($file, '.') == TRUE){
        }else{
            if (file_exists($directory.$file.'/zconfirmed.txt')){
                echo '<script>console.log("display_subdirectories.php says: '.$directory.$file.'/zconfirmed.txt");</script><li class=""><a class="w3-btn w3-green" href="' .$URL.$file. '" >' .$file. '</a></li>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<script>console.log("display_subdirectories.php says: '.$directory.$file.'");</script><li class="bold"><a class="w3-btn w3-red" href="' .$URL.$file. '" >' .$file. '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's My problem. If there is only 1 directory that has the zconfirmed.txt file in it, it doesn't appear when I iterate through the array. If there are 2 or more, it works just fine. Anybody have an answer or even something I can do to better troubleshoot this code?

I'm just trying to list the directories in the order of their last modified date/time.

Thank you guys so much for the help!

Comment: Try adding some `echo`s or `var_dump()`s in key points in your script to figure out what the variable(s) contain and work through your logic of why it's working how it is.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will have it report to the console each step along the way and, if that doesn't help, I'll post a reply. Sometimes I get worked up into a tizzy and forget the basics - like see what's in the array. Ty.

Comment: instead of using <script>console.log... use print_r($variableYouWantToOutput);die;

Answer (score 0):

You are already storing the filename in the array couldn't you change your foreach loop to something simpler like

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ($file == "zconfirmed.txt") {
        echo '<script>console.log("display_subdirectories.php says: '.$directory.$file.'/zconfirmed.txt");</script><li class=""><a class="w3-btn w3-green" href="' .$URL.$file. '" >' .$file. '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have missed the '/' in there. zconfirmed.txt is a child of $file. so it's directory/file/zconfirmed.txt (if present). Or... I may have missed something in your code?

Comment: I'm not checking for file_exists() the filename should be in the array. I didn't think DirectoryIterator put the full path in, just the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
  echo '<div id="subdirectories"><h3>Subdirectories:</h3><ul>';

    $files = scandir($directory); 
    $dir = array();
    foreach ($files as $file){
        if (checkDirectory($file) == true){
            $filetime = filemtime($directory.$file);
            $filename = $file;
            $dir[$filetime] =  $filename;
        }
    }
    ksort($dir);
    $files = $dir;

    foreach ($files as $time=>$file){
        $contiansPhotos = FALSE;
        $path = $directory.$file;
        $dirs = glob($path.'/{zconfirmed.txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($dirs as $dir) {
            $contiansPhotos = TRUE;
        }
        if($contiansPhotos === TRUE){
            echo '<li class=""><a class="w3-btn w3-green" href="' .$URL.$file. '" >' .$file. '</a></li>';
        }
    }//foreach $files as $file;

    foreach ($files as $time=>$file){
        $contiansPhotos = FALSE;
        $path = $directory.$file;
        $dirs = glob($path.'/{zconfirmed.txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($dirs as $dir) {
            $contiansPhotos = TRUE;
        }
        if($contiansPhotos === FALSE){
            echo '<li class="bold"><a class="w3-btn w3-red" href="' .$URL.$file. '" >' .$file. '</a></li>';
        }
    }//foreach $files as $file;

    echo '</ul></div>';
```